# How can I hide this section only on desktop?

Tags: ruby, shopify, themes, liquid

```
{{ 'section-image-banner.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

{%- if section.settings.adapt_height_first_image and section.settings.image != blank -%}
  {%- style -%}
  @media screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }} .banner__media::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}:not(.banner--mobile-bottom) .banner__content::before {
      padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }} .banner__media::before {
      padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
    }
  }
  {%- endstyle -%}
{%- endif -%}

{%- style -%}
  #Banner-{{ section.id }}::after {
    opacity: {{ section.settings.image_overlay_opacity | divided_by: 100.0 }};
  }
{%- endstyle -%}

<div id="Banner-{{ section.id }}" class=" {{ section.settings.show_on_device }} banner banner--content-align-{{ section.settings.desktop_content_alignment }} banner--content-align-mobile-{{ section.settings.mobile_content_alignment }} banner--{{ section.settings.image_height }}{% if section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile and section.settings.image != blank and section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner--stacked{% endif %}{% if section.settings.adapt_height_first_image and section.settings.image != blank %} banner--adapt{% endif %}{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} banner--mobile-bottom{%- endif -%}{% if section.settings.show_text_box == false %} banner--desktop-transparent{% endif %}">
  {%- if section.settings.image != blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image == blank and section.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {%-liquid
        assign image_height = section.settings.image.width | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio
        if section.settings.image_2 != blank
          assign image_class = "banner__media-image-half"
        endif
        if section.settings.image_2 != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile
          assign sizes = "(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw"
        elsif section.settings.image_2 != blank
          assign sizes = "50vw"
        else
          assign sizes = "100vw"
        endif
      -%}
      {{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 1500 | image_tag:
        loading: 'lazy',
        width: section.settings.image.width,
        height: image_height,
        class: image_class,
        sizes: sizes,
        widths: '375, 550, 750, 1100, 1500, 1780, 2000, 3000, 3840',
        alt: section.settings.image.alt | escape
      }}
    </div>
  {%- elsif section.settings.image_2 == blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image == blank and section.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {{ 'lifestyle-2' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if section.settings.image_2 != blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {%-liquid
        assign image_height_2 = section.settings.image_2.width | divided_by: section.settings.image_2.aspect_ratio
        if section.settings.image != blank
          assign image_class_2 = "banner__media-image-half"
        endif
        if section.settings.image != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile
          assign sizes = "(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw"
        elsif section.settings.image != blank
          assign sizes = "50vw"
        else
          assign sizes = "100vw"
        endif
      -%}
      {{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1500 | image_tag:
        loading: 'lazy',
        width: section.settings.image_2.width,
        height: image_height_2,
        class: image_class_2,
        sizes: sizes,
        widths: '375, 550, 750, 1100, 1500, 1780, 2000, 3000, 3840',
        alt: section.settings.image_2.alt | escape
      }}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  <div class="banner__content banner__content--{{ section.settings.desktop_content_position }} page-width">
    <div class="banner__box content-container content-container--full-width-mobile color-{{ section.settings.color_scheme }} gradient">
      {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        {%- case block.type -%}
          {%- when 'heading' -%}
            <h2 class="banner__heading {{ block.settings.heading_size }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <span>{{ block.settings.heading | escape }}</span>
            </h2>
          {%- when 'text' -%}
            <div class="banner__text {{ block.settings.text_style }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <span>{{ block.settings.text | escape }}</span>
            </div>
          {%- when 'buttons' -%}
            <div class="banner__buttons{% if block.settings.button_label_1 != blank and block.settings.button_label_2 != blank %} banner__buttons--multiple{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              {%- if block.settings.button_label_1 != blank -%}
                <a{% if block.settings.button_link_1 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_1 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_1 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_1 | escape }}</a>
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- if block.settings.button_label_2 != blank -%}
                <a{% if block.settings.button_link_2 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_2 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_2 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_2 | escape }}</a>
              {%- endif -%}

            </div>
        {%- endcase -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding on min-width: 750px display: none; but didn't work. I'm looking to hide this section on shopify theme (dawn).
even tried with !important. Tried also doing banner-{ display none.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of your snippet, this should hide the section wrapper that Shopify wraps your section code with, if screen width is `750px` or more.

```html
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 750px){
  #shopify-section-{{ section.id }} {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```